# Failing to create List in jQuery Mobile

Tags: json, rest, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a rest service that gives me the following json

```
[
   {
      "vendorId":1,
      "product":[
         {
            "productId":1,
            "name":"Coffee",
            "baseprice":2.00,
            "productoption":[
               {
                  "productOptionId":1,
                  "topping":"honeymustard",
                  "baseprice":0.30
               },
               {
                  "productOptionId":2,
                  "topping":"barbeque",
                  "baseprice":0.50
               },
               {
                  "productOptionId":3,
                  "topping":"whipcream",
                  "baseprice":0.50
               }
            ],
            "productSubOption":[
               {
                  "productSubOptionId":1,
                  "size":"Small",
                  "baseprice":0.50
               },
               {
                  "productSubOptionId":2,
                  "size":"Medium",
                  "baseprice":0.50
               },
               {
                  "productSubOptionId":3,
                  "size":"Large",
                  "baseprice":0.50
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "productId":2,
            "name":"Burger",
            "baseprice":2.00,
            "productoption":[
               {
                  "productOptionId":4,
                  "topping":"mayo",
                  "baseprice":0.50
               },
               {
                  "productOptionId":5,
                  "topping":"onion",
                  "baseprice":0.50
               }
            ],
            "productSubOption":[
               {
                  "productSubOptionId":4,
                  "size":"Small",
                  "baseprice":0.50
               },
               {
                  "productSubOptionId":5,
                  "size":"Medium",
                  "baseprice":0.50
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "vendorName":"XYZ",
   }
]
```

I want to show the list of names of vendors when I open my mobile application.
This is what i wrote..

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="vendors">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Oc Welcome</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="vendors-list" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true"></ul>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>orderchief.com</h4>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>

<script>
$('#vendors').live("pageshow",function(){
    $.getJSON('http://192.168.1.2:8080/server/getVendors' , function(data){
        var list = "";
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            list += '<li class="row">'+value.vendorName+'</li>';
        });
        $('#vendors-list').html(list).trigger('create');
        $('#vendors-list').listview('refresh');
    })
}

</script>
```

I have looked through other posts but i am new to jquery so it is difficult to understand the solution. Am i missing something? My content section of the page looks empty when i open this in chrome. I am planning to use it with phonegap in next step. Are there some changes that i will have to make?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: version of what.. jquery is 1.2.0

Comment: you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7WH2L/

Comment: yes that is correct. But i want to show the list of product inside each vendor and each product wil hold a list of product options as check boxes..i guess i should have added that in my question too... But yes you did give me solution for this one.

Comment: How do i create that object? Can you show me with a getJson?

Comment: JSON object depends on how you create it server-side. In your example, you have to loop through each _product_ object to read its' contents.

Comment: sorry, it is not clear for me yet. What do you mean creating on server side? My server i just giving the json string that i pasted above. How do i get that string and apply the same list creation process you showed on jsfiddle.

Comment: here's a sample http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7WH2L/ You need to loop inside each object `data[key].product` and inside them, there are other objects and arrays.

Comment: thanks! I think my getJson is not going to the localhost url. Do you think it is right to use localhost url in getJson? Should i use JSONP for such purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of head banging and hair pulling i finally found out the reason i got an empty list.

This had to do with CORS.

these posts helped
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

http://zhentao-li.blogspot.ca/2012/06/enable-cors-support-in-rest-services.html

If you are not using @EnableAutoConfiguration (which does not require web.xml - spring-boot-autoconfigure feature) you have to add your filter classes to web.xml manually as follows

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.zhentao.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```